# remove specific field after clicking back in browser or using history.go(-1)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, browser-history

i have a form with a capacha, if the capacha was entered wrong, after submit the page is doing a "history.go(-1)" and all fields include the capacha input are back on the screen

right now i have a js that clear that - but now that i need it in several places, i want to know if it possible to clear a form field after back  with something related to the html form or what ever

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking into [cache controlling](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html) the CAPTCHA image (or the page that loads it up)?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bad idea to use "history.go(-1)" and JavaScript at all.
You must validate captcha on the server side and in server side choice that page you must render? again with captcha or next.

Comment: the Capacha is server side, but when finished with error it send back with history.back - it is a code from the internet that my boss got for 45$

Comment: Ok. if captcha is serverside. Why you can't rerander captcha page if captcha is wrong?

Comment: because i send the page trought a form on a page that rebuilding it from querystring will talk more work

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its possible with only html, need to add some programming.

You can have js function that is called on `onload` event of document.

function can be like this:

```
function resetfields()
{
  $("input[type=text]").val("");
  $("textarea").val(""); // if any textarea
}
```

And you can also use some ajax in this function to get a new captcha every time.

you can place this function in your master/header page, so that you don't need to copy it to all pages (for that you may need to make selector more precise).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is that you can rename the form field with every visit to the page. Append a timestamp to the name. That way the browser won't autofill it. You probably will have to adjust your backend code slightly to account for this.